# Retrieve the two highest item from a list containing 100,000 integers

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can retrieve the two highest item from a list containing 100,000 integers without having to sort the entire list first?

Answer (score 68):

Use [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).  This is the most flexible approach in case you ever want to handle more than just the top two elements.

Here's an example.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> import random
>>> x = range(100000)
>>> random.shuffle(x)
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, x)
[99999, 99998]
```

Comment: Sorry for being petty, but this doesn't really answer the question. The OP specifically asked for a solution without sorting the list - while the docs for heapq.nlargest specifically say it's equivalent to sort.

Comment: @Korem it provides an equivalent *result*.

Comment: @FogleBird I don't want to get into an argument. It is an equivalent result, but the OP also asked for the way. This is O(nlogn) instead of O(n), and against what the OP asked. An equivalent result could also be provided in R, but that also won't be what the OP asked.

Comment: @Korem I believe it's actually O(nlogk) where k in this case is 2. (The heap only reaches this size.)

Comment: I ran a test and found nlargest to be twice as fast as sorting with a shuffled list of length 1000. (`nlargest(2, x)` vs. `sorted(x, reverse=True)[:2]`)

Comment: @FogleBird That's interesting. I'm glad I commented, I learned something new.

Comment: @Korem To clarify, it doesn't actually sort the whole thing, just the list of the top elements it's seen so far. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 19):

[JacobM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-2-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers/2739090#2739090) is absolutely the way to go. However, there are a few things to keep in mind while implementing what he described. Here's a little play-along-at-home tutorial to guide you through the trickier parts of solving this problem.

*If this code is meant for production use, please use one of the more efficient/concise answers listed. This answer is targetted at someone new to programming.*

## The idea

The idea is simple.

- Keep two variables: `largest` and `second_largest`.
- Go through the list.

  - If an item is greater than `largest`, assign it to `largest`.
  - If an item is greater than `second_largest`, but less than `largest`, assign it to `second_largest`.

## Getting started

Let's start.

```
def two_largest(inlist):
    """Return the two largest items in the sequence. The sequence must
    contain at least two items."""
    for item in inlist:
        if item > largest:
            largest = item
        elif largest > item > second_largest:
            second_largest = item
    # Return the results as a tuple
    return largest, second_largest

# If we run this script, it will should find the two largest items and
# print those
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inlist = [3, 2, 1]
    print two_largest(inlist)
```

Okay, we now have JacobM's answer as a Python function. What happens when we try to run it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twol.py", line 10, in <module>
    print two_largest(inlist)
  File "twol.py", line 3, in two_largest
    if item > largest:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'largest' referenced before assignment
```

Apparently, we need to set `largest` before we start the loop. This probably means we should set `second_largest` too.

## Initializing variables

Let's set `largest` and `second_largest` to 0.

```
def two_largest(inlist):
    """Return the two largest items in the sequence. The sequence must
    contain at least two items."""
    largest = 0 # NEW!
    second_largest = 0 # NEW!
    for item in inlist:
        if item > largest:
            largest = item
        elif largest > item > second_largest:
            second_largest = item
    # Return the results as a tuple
    return largest, second_largest

# If we run this script, it will should find the two largest items and
# print those
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inlist = [3, 2, 1]
    print two_largest(inlist)
```

Good. Let's run it.

```
(3, 2)
```

Great! Now let's test with `inlist` being `[1, 2, 3]`

```
    inlist = [1, 2, 3] # CHANGED!
```

Let's try it.

```
(3, 0)
```

...Uh oh.

## Fixing the logic

The largest value (3) seems correct. The second-largest value is completely wrong though. What's going on?

Let's work through what the function is doing.

- When we start, `largest` is 0 and `second_largest` is also 0.
- The first item in the list we look at is 1, so `largest` becomes 1.
- The next item is 2, so `largest` becomes 2.

But what about `second_largest`?

When we assign a new value to `largest`, the largest value actually becomes second-largest. We need to show that in the code.

```
def two_largest(inlist):
    """Return the two largest items in the sequence. The sequence must
    contain at least two items."""
    largest = 0
    second_largest = 0
    for item in inlist:
        if item > largest:
            second_largest = largest # NEW!
            largest = item
        elif largest > item > second_largest:
            second_largest = item
    # Return the results as a tuple
    return largest, second_largest

# If we run this script, it will should find the two largest items and
# print those
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inlist = [1, 2, 3]
    print two_largest(inlist)
```

Let's run it.

```
(3, 2)
```

Fantastic.

## Initializing variables, part 2

Now let's try it with a list of negative numbers.

```
    inlist = [-1, -2, -3] # CHANGED!
```

Let's run it.

```
(0, 0)
```

That's not right at all. Where did these zeroes come from?

It turns out that the starting values for `largest` and `second_largest` were actually larger than all the items in the list. The first thing you might consider is setting `largest` and `second_largest` to the lowest values possible in Python. Unfortunately, Python doesn't have a smallest possible value. That means that, even if you set both of them to -1,000,000,000,000,000,000, you can have a list of values smaller than that.

So what's the best thing to do? Let's try setting `largest` and `second_largest` to the first and second items in the list. Then, to avoid double-counting any items in the list, we only look at the part of the list after the second item.

```
def two_largest(inlist):
    """Return the two largest items in the sequence. The sequence must
    contain at least two items."""
    largest = inlist[0] # CHANGED!
    second_largest = inlist[1] # CHANGED!
    # Only look at the part of inlist starting with item 2
    for item in inlist[2:]: # CHANGED!
        if item > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = item
        elif largest > item > second_largest:
            second_largest = item
    # Return the results as a tuple
    return largest, second_largest

# If we run this script, it will should find the two largest items and
# print those
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inlist = [-1, -2, -3]
    print two_largest(inlist)
```

Let's run it.

```
(-1, -2)
```

Great! Let's try with another list of negative numbers.

```
    inlist = [-3, -2, -1] # CHANGED!
```

Let's run it.

```
(-1, -3)
```

Wait, what?

## Initializing variables, part 3

Let's step through our logic again.

- `largest` is set to -3
- `second_largest` is set to -2

Wait right there. Already, this seems wrong. -2 is larger than -3. Is this what caused the problem? Let's continue.

- `largest` is set to -1; `second_largest` is set to the old value of `largest`, which is -3

Yes, that looks to be the problem. We need to ensure that `largest` and `second_largest` are set correctly.

```
def two_largest(inlist):
    """Return the two largest items in the sequence. The sequence must
    contain at least two items."""
    if inlist[0] > inlist[1]: # NEW
        largest = inlist[0]
        second_largest = inlist[1]
    else: # NEW
        largest = inlist[1] # NEW
        second_largest = inlist[0] # NEW
    # Only look at the part of inlist starting with item 2
    for item in inlist[2:]:
        if item > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = item
        elif largest > item > second_largest:
            second_largest = item
    # Return the results as a tuple
    return largest, second_largest

# If we run this script, it will should find the two largest items and
# print those
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inlist = [-3, -2, -1]
    print two_largest(inlist)
```

Let's run it.

```
(-1, -2)
```

Excellent.

## Conclusion

So here's the code, nicely commented and formatted. It's also had all the bugs I could find beaten from it. Enjoy.

However, assuming this really is a homework question, I hope you get some useful experience from seeing an imperfect piece of code slowly improved. I hope some of these techniques will be useful in future programming assignments.

---

## Efficiency

Not very efficient. But for most purposes, it should be okay: on my computer (Core 2 Duo), a list of 100 000 items can be processed in 0.27 seconds (using `timeit`, averaged over 100 runs).

Comment: i don't think that Wesley solution is good. I think, instead, that is horrible.(maybe is useful to teach how to fix a code)

Simple is better than complex.

we have a lots of solutions, and we have to take the simpler. the use of 'for' or 'while' on a  list of 100.000 integers is a folly

Comment: It's a shame you wrote a diatribe while there is `heapq.nlargest` :)

Comment: heapq sure might be the way to go in production code, but it's much easier to explain a for loop to a new programmer than a heap data structure. Hopefully some new programmer finds this useful someday. Maybe.

Comment: OK, now what if I want the top 3? Or 4? This approach is naive and bug-prone (as you've shown).

Comment: If your goal is to teach, we should be explaining heaps and why they are good for this task.

Comment: Should be `largest >= item > second_largest` if you have multiple copies of the same value inside your list. Since you have the check `largest < item` just before you can simplify `largest >= item > second_largest` to `item > second_largest`.

Comment: What's wrong with this initialization? `largest = -2**32 + 1` and `second_largest = -2**32`

Answer (score 6):

You iterate over the list, maintaining variables that contain the value of the highest and the second highest item encountered thus far.  Each new item that is encountered will replace whichever of the two the new item is higher than (if any).

Comment: This is the way to go. O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @Jacob, what would be the best way to generalize this to top n variables? I cant get my head around maintaining the top n. would you use a list? and sort that list?

Comment: @kamula The tricky bit with the top N items would be avoiding comparing each new item with all of the top N items. If N is large, your best bet might be to store the top N variables in some sort of binary tree, so that for each new item, you can quickly determine which item (if any) it should replace. It might also be worthwhile to separately maintain variables of the highest item and the Nth item you've seen so far, so you can tell quickly, for each new item, whether you need to delve into your tree (you only need to search the tree if the new item is between the top item and the Nth item).

Answer (score 5):

A really slick way is to use `heapq`.  [Heapify the array](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) (O(n)), then just pop an many elements that you need (log(n)).  (Saw this question in an interview once, good question to keep in mind.)

Comment: +1. This is a good approach. Only thing is that the heap serves as a priority queue. It's not sorted and the only reliable thing is the top of the queue will be the largest. So, after popping that out, you'll have to heapify the queue once again(log(n) like zdav's mentioned). It doesn't change the asymptotic time but one should be aware of this.

Comment: Agreed @Noufal, if you just use heappop, the re-heapifying is taken care of.

Comment: I like the answer, but saying that this is not sorted is a bit of a stretch.  Certainly, this is not linearly sorted, but there is a degree of sorting going on.

Comment: If you knew about heapq, you should've known about: http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest

Comment: @Jeff B: finding the first (or equivalently the last) M elements of the sort of a list necessarily involves some sorting. This way is more up-front about it than the "simple" hand-coded loop, but unfortunately it also does more *of* it, and takes more space also...

Comment: Very right @FogleBird, I forgot all about `nlargest`, that function makes the solution a one-liner!

Comment: @FogleBird. I haven't used heapq myself. I was making a statement about heaps as a data structure. Your point is very valid.

Answer (score 4):

**"2 highest" is impossible; only one item can be "highest".** Perhaps you mean "highest 2". In any case, you need to say what to do when the list contains duplicates.  What do you want from [8, 9, 10, 10]: (10, 9) or (10, 10)? If your response is (10, 10), please consider input of [8, 9, 10, 10, 10]. What are you going to do with the "highest two" when you've got them? Please edit your question to give this guidance.

In the meantime, here's an answer that takes the first approach (two unique values):

```
largest = max(inlist)
second_largest = max(item for item in inlist if item < largest)
```

You should add guards against fewer than 2 unique values in the list.

Comment: The heapq.nlargest suggestion above will return [10,10] if there are duplicates.  If you don't care about duplicates, then pass the list through set() first, i.e. heapq.nlargest(2, set(my_list))

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list, and if list is not null, extract last two element

```
>>> a=[0,6,8,5,10,5]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[0, 5, 5, 6, 8, 10]
>>> if a:
...  print a[-1],a[-2]
... 
10 8
```

Simple and most efficient:)

Now if sorting is not required, find max, remove max, find max again

```
>>> a=[0,6,8,5,10,5]
>>> max(a)
10
>>> a.remove(max(a))
>>> max(a)
8
>>>
```

Of course, you will lose the original list but you can create a temporary list as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but I don't know if you want to retain the items in the list:

```
max1 = max(myList)
myList.remove(max1)
max2 = max(myList)
```

If you do, you can do this:

```
max1 = max(myList)
idx1 = myList.index(max1)
myList.pop(idx1)

max2 = max(myList)
myList.insert(idx1,max1)
```

Comment: Both of these iterate over `myList` three times, where only one iteration is really necessary.

Comment: I understand.  This requires less algorithm however, and sometimes that's what people want.  If it were me, I would sort or traverse the list.  Those methods have already been covered several times in the answers.

Comment: @Jeff, Sorting would scale worse than this.

Comment: Yeah, I guess O(3n) is better than O(n log n). :)  Traversing the array, retaining maximum values along the way is O(n), which == O(3n).  In real time, they may differ by a factor of 3 worst case, but in terms of scalability, they are equivalent.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote on this?  It is a valid answer.  May not be the best answer, but it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your `List` to `List_copy`.
Retrieve the highest value and get its position by:

```
Highest_value = max(List_copy)
Highest_position = List_copy.index(max(List_copy))
```

Assign `0` to the `Highest_value`.

```
List_copy[Highest_position] = 0
```

And run your line again.

```
Second_Highest = max(List_copy)
```

Comment: Copying the entire list is hardly necessary. I strongly recommend reading some of the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old, but here is a simple solution to this problem. Tested against heapq.nlargest and this is a bit faster (no sorting needed):

Works for both positive and negative numbers.

Function below: Max time used: 0.12, max memory used: 29290496
heapq.nlargest: Max time used: 0.14, max memory used: 31088640

```
def two_highest_numbers(list_to_work):

    first = None
    second = None

    for number in list_to_work:
        if first is None:
            first = number
        elif number > first:
            second = first
            first = number
        else:
            if second is None:
                second = number
            elif number > second:
                second = number

return [first, second]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the entire list is the only way to do it without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting the list the only way to really do it is to iterate through the whole list and save the highest two numbers.  I think you'd be better off sorting the list.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that this list of numbers is going to change at some point.  If your list is sorted you don't have to iterate every time to find the maximum numbers.  If you take it a step further and store your data structure in some sort of binary tree, you will be able to pull the maximum numbers extremely fast. (as well as any other operations you want, such as checking for duplicates, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The second highest item is a fairly simple case, but for the kth highest item what you want is a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).  That page is pretty thorough so it's probably best just to read that.

Answer (score 0):

The best time you can expect is linear, since you have to at least look through all the elements.

Here is my pseudocode to solve the problem:

```
//assume list has at least 2 elements
(max, nextMax) = if (list[0] > list[1])
                 then (list[0], list[1])
                 else (list[1], list[0])

for (2 <= i < length) {
    (max, nextMax) = if       (max < list[i])     => (list[i], max)
                     elseif   (nextMax < list[i]) => (max, list[i])
                     else     (no change)         => (max, nextMax)
}

return (max, nextMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that uses only base Python functions can be seen below:

```
>>> largest = max(lst)
>>> maxIndex = lst.index(largest)
>>> secondLargest = max(max(lst[:maxIndex]), max(lst[maxIndex+1:]))
```

If we split a list around its largest number, we know that the second largest number is either in the left half or the right half. So, we can trivially find the second largest number by simply finding the larger of the largest number in the left and right half of the list.

It's trivial to show this is O(n) time and O(1) space. We traverse the list once to find the largest element, then again to find the second largest. We only store the largest values themselves and the index of the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalism and simplicity first. There are a lot of situations where you only want the two, or maybe three, greatest values. Using a heap can consume memory and has some slight performance overhead; however, that depends on whether the heap used is implemented natively, which could outperform the scripted algorithm. Sorting is also a lot of overhead.

```py
def greatest_two_values(nums):
    assert len(nums) > 1, "len(`nums`) < 2"
    v1 = 0
    v2 = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n > v1:
            v2 = v1
            v1 = n
        elif n > v2:
            v2 = n
    return v1, v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your list in a `ndarray` temporarily:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,99,100])
>>> b = [np.max(np.delete(a, np.argmax(a))), np.max(a)]
>>> print(b)
[99, 100]
```

To retrieve the indices, just switch to three `np.argmax()`'s:

```
>>> b = [np.argmax(np.delete(a, np.argmax(a))), np.argmax(a)]
>>> print(b)
[3, 4]
```

If speed is an issue, speed up `numpy` with [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)