# Find second largest element in list with repeated elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list with several very big values set on purpose to differentiate those indexes, it looks like this:

```
a = [1.3, 2.1, 9999., 5., 3.7 ,6.6, 9999., 7.4, 9999., 3.5, 7, 1.2, 9999.]
```

I need to find the second largest value in that list which *isn't* equal to `9999.` (in the case above it would be `7.4`) in the most efficient way possible (my list can get quite big)

In this question [Retrieve the two highest item from a list containing 100,000 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-two-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers) the `heapq.nlargest` function is mentioned but since I have more than one value `9999.` it wouldn't work.

Comment: Second largest, or largest not equal to 9999 ?

Comment: Largest not equal to 9999. I call it *second largest* because I think of all those 9999 values as the same thing, but perhaps this is a bit confusing. Should I edit the name of the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternate method:

```
>>> a = [1.3, 2.1, 9999., 5., 3.7 ,6.6, 9999., 7.4, 9999., 3.5, 7, 1.2, 9999.]
>>> sorted(set(a))[-2]
7.4
>>>
```

And, believe it or not, it is actually quite a lot faster than the accepted solution:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("a=range(10000000);print sorted(set(a))[-2]", number=10)
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
34.327036257401424
>>> # This is NPE's answer
>>> timeit("a=range(10000000);maxa = max(a);print max(val for val in a if val != maxa)", number=10)
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
9999998
53.22811809880869
>>>
```

Above is a test that runs 10 times and works with a list that contains 10,000,000 items.  Unless there is a flaw in my test (which I don't think there is), the solution I gave is clearly much faster.

Comment: I can't believe it!  But it's working for me too.  +1 for now!  Perhaps `range()` gives an already-sorted list and therefore isn't 'fair'?

Comment: I also tried `a=[ i%10 for i in range(1000000) ];` and got the same results.  Fascinating.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - Regardless of whether the list is sorted or not to begin with, Python still has to check it.  After all, how does the computer know its sorted?  I think I'm right in saying the computer can't, so it sorts the list anyways.  Also, I gave NPE's answer a sorted list too, so all is fair.

Comment: Usually people say quicksort has complexity N log N, but that's only on average.  If the data is ordered in a really nasty way, the complexity jumps to N^2.  Or it can be O(N) on data that's already in the right order (but this depends).  So, yes, it has to sort it anyway, as you say.  The issue is that perhaps the sorting completes much more quickly on your contrived dataset than it would on random data.

Comment: Excellent, I've changed the accepted answer to this one since performance was at the center of the question and this is the one that performs the best. Thank you all!

Comment: CPython doesn't use quicksort.  Given an already-sorted (or reverse-sorted) list of length N, Python's sort detects that after exactly N-1 comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> max(val for val in a if val != 9999)
7.4
```

This has `O(n)` time complexity.

If the `9999` isn't fixed, you can generalize this by using `max(a)` instead of `9999`:

```
>>> maxa = max(a)
>>> max(val for val in a if val != maxa)
7.4
```

(Although I suspect this isn't what you want.)

Comment: Or `if val != max(a)`

Comment: Just make sure you call `max(a)` outside for the generator.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = set([1.3, 2.1, 9999., 5., 3.7 ,6.6, 9999., 7.4, 9999., 3.5, 7, 1.2, 9999.])
a.remove(max(a))
print max(a)
```

This uses `set` to make sure that we deal with only unique items and then we remove the maximum value, so that next time when we call `max`, we ll be left with the second best maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy you can use masked arrays to skip 'bad' values:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.3, 2.1, 9999., 5., 3.7 ,6.6, 9999., 7.4, 9999., 3.5, 7, 1.2, 9999.])
ma = np.ma.masked_values(a, 9999., copy=False)
ma.max()
7.4
```

you can easily add exclusions to your mask:

```
ma = np.ma.masked_values(ma, 7.4, copy=False)
ma.max()
7.0
ma.mask[ma>=5]=True   
ma.max()
3.7
```