# How to finding maximum values in list in python without using loops

Tags: python, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I am trying to find the two largest elements of a given list of numbers using list comprehension.

This is what I have tried so far. I also tried to use the 'filter' function in place of this.

```
def top_two(l):
    l1 = [lambda x,y:x > y for x in l]
    return l1
```

I also tried something like this but it is not working either.

```
def top_two(l):
    l1 = [l[x] for x in range(len(l)) for y in l[x:] if l[x] > y]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

***EDIT*** I had not thought of simply sorting it! I will sort it with list comprehensions and extract the max. Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting us to do your homework? Please come up with a general solution to the problem and then ask specific questions for specific problems.

Comment: my apologies! this is not a homework question, just something which I am trying to solve.

Comment: Can you sort it and take the last two elements? Or are you strictly supposed to use list comprehensions

Comment: the thing you edited out resembled an assignment.

Comment: Ten lines are definably enough for writing a sorting function in python

Comment: it is a question that I am doing for my own practice in order to become comfortable with list comprehensions. I promise you it is not for homework. and @SruthiV yes I would like to try it with a list comprehension method.

Comment: it would be good if you post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-two-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers

Comment: I believe if we add to the title that it has to be FP, then it is a different question

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sort the list and get the biggest two numbers. I copy and pasted bubble sort code from [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html)

```
def top_two(l):
    for n in range(len(l)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(n):
            if l[i]>l[i+1]:
                temp = l[i]
                l[i] = l[i+1]
                l[i+1] = temp
    return l[-1],l[-2]
```

Comment: thank you, you have a good idea! I think I will try to use quicksort with list comprehensions and then extract the maximums.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is a solution, but for long lists it might be more expensive than needed as it is not linear. Python is far from the most elegant language for FP, but you could use `reduce` to find your largest elements in one pass.

```
def add_largest_to_pair(pair, num):
    # This function takes a pair and a number and returns a pair made of the two largest of those three
    if pair[1] > num >= pair[0]:
        return (num, pair[1])
    elif num >= pair[1]:
        return (pair[1], num)
    else:
        return pair

def top_two(l):
    return reduce(
        add_largest_to_pair,
        l,
        (float('-inf'), float('-inf'))
    )
```

This will return you a tuple of the two largest values, with `pair[0]` being the second largest and `pair[1]` being the largest. Just be aware that this assumes your list has at least length two.

**Note**: You will have to use `functools.reduce` if you are using Python3.