# How to create a function in Python that receives a list of numbers and return the sum of the two largest numbers in that array?

Tags: python, list

I came up with something like this:

```
def sumLargestNumbers (x):
    for largest_integer in x:
        largest_integer = max(sumLargestNumbers)
        integers.remove(largest_integer)
    return (sum(largest_integer, integers.remove))
```

But it gives me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) 
  <ipython-input-15-2b77832140c8> in <module>
      1 x = [1, 10]
----> 2 print(sumLargestNumbers([1, 10]))

  <ipython-input-14-b3557ee34db3> in sumLargestNumbers(x)
      1 def sumLargestNumbers (x):
      2     for largest_integer in x:
----> 3         largest_integer = max(sumLargestNumbers)
      4         integers.remove(largest_integer)
      5     return (sum(largest_integer, integers.remove))

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Any help please?

Comment: Most of your code doesn’t really make sense. To get the largest number in `x` use `max(x)`. You don’t need a loop. I also don’t understand why you thought you should pass the function `sumLargestNumbers` to `max`. This doesn’t make sense and gives you this error.

Comment: Related: [Retrieve the two highest item from a list containing 100,000 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2739051/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sort the array using built-in method sorted, then take the last 2 elements in the sorted (in ascending order) and sum them using the built-in method sum:

```
def sumLargestNumbers(x):
    return sum(sorted(x)[-2:])
```

Comment: damn it seems so easy when you have the answer! Thank a lot!

Comment: It's my pleasure

Comment: @hmd - Sounds like this is what you wanted. Accept the answer then the rest of us know we don't need to cook something else up.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumLargestNumbers(arr):
    return sum(sorted(arr)[-2:])

print(sumLargestNumbers([4,5,6]))
# returns 11
```

Read about slicing; the [-2:] part selects last two items of the list.

Python uses [start:step:stop] notation in a number of places, one of them being indices of lists. Here, it's just [start:] because we want the default stop and step (which is *till the end* and 1 respectively).
Another trick here is **negative index**. It bascally means we're starting to count from the end. `my_list[-1]` would be the last element, `my_list[-2]` would be the second to last and so on.
The colon means that we take a *slice* of the list, not just a single element.

Comment: duplicate of [Gil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63652299/4518341)

Comment: Great minds think alike. Or rather, it's the result of the fact that such simple problems have an obvious answer.  I guess he has been a minute faster though.