# How to get best two tuples out of a large list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, top-n

I have a Python list contains lots of tuples. I want to find the best **two tuples** such that which have the best two **max range** values in it.

```
list_ = [(55, 55), (77, 81), (95, 129)]
```

So in this example, I should be able to recover the `(77, 81), (95, 129)`. Because `81-77` and `129-95` gives the **largest range**.
How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Are the tuples always sorted? That is, the first item is always lower than the second?

Comment: Sort the list by range and take the first/last 2?

Comment: @DeepSpace It works, but it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman.. yes!

Comment: Try do what @DeepSpace suggested and check if that have a noticeable overhead

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That solution is O(nlogn). Trying to get an O(n) solution (with likely a larger memory complexity, overhead and readability) is not worth it in this case IMHO

Comment: Please share the code you’ve written to try solve this problem, and show the results.

Comment: thanks @ChayimFriedman & DeepSpace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve the two highest item from a list containing 100,000 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-two-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) with a custom key should do the trick:

```py
from heapq import nlargest
list_ = [(55, 55), (77, 81), (95, 129)]
result = nlargest(2, list_, key = lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
```

Comment: I was about to answer using slightly different approach but this one is more clean and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

```
def getMaxTwoTuples(list_):
  max_tuple = []
  for i in range(2):
    max_tuples = [i[0]+ i[1] for i in list_]
    m = max(max_tuples)
    index  =  max_tuples.index(m)
    max_tuple.append(list_[index])
    list_.pop(index)
  return max_tuple
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer might be improved by including an explanation for the code you've provided.