# Sorting directory by date Python

Tags: python

I have the following directory format:

```
logs
---- abc_090000_20210124
---- abc_091500_20210124
etc...
```

The format is `abc_(HHMMSS)_(YYYYMMDD)`

I want to get the two most recent files by date and time.

If they are all on the same day I use this code:

```
directory = os.listdir("logs")
base = "abc"

date = sorted([x.split("_")[2] for x in directory])[-1]

t_of_day = sorted([x.split("_")[1] for x in directory if x.split("_")[2] == date])

a = f"logs/{base}_{t_of_day[-1]}_{date}"
b = f"logs/{base}_{t_of_day[-2]}_{date}"
print(a,b)
```

and it works properly, however, at the change of day the files will change like so:

```
...
---- abc_234506_20210124
---- abc_000007_20210125
...
```

and my code will give an error as there will not be two values in the list `t_of_day`.

I am unsure of how I could change this to suit my situation.

I have tried to use a condition where `if date[-1] == date[-2]` to use a different value, but as the dataset builds up this may become unreliable.

Is there perhaps an alternative way to sort the files? I must state that changing the file names is **not** an option.

Comment: you should use the `datetime` module to conver the date to a datetime object and sort on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply your own function as the [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) argument to determine how a list is sorted.

```py
import os

def date_sort(filename):
    abc, hms, ymd = filename.split('_')
    return ymd + hms

filenames = os.listdir('logs')
filenames.sort(key=date_sort)
```

You could also use Python's `datetime` class, but I don't think it's necessary for simply sorting values like this. All you need are the units of time in descending size: year, month, day, hour, minute, second.

For just getting the two most recent, you don't really need to sort the whole list, but you can still use this same key function for "sorting" a heap queue. (Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739310/12975140) that gives a good example using `heapq`.)

```py
import os
import heapq

def date_sort(filename):
    abc, hms, ymd = filename.split('_')
    return ymd + hms

filenames = os.listdir('logs')
first, second = heapq.nlargest(2, filenames, key=date_sort)
```

If you decide you would like to use `datetime`, you should get the same results by altering your sort function to return a `datetime` object using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```py
from datetime import datetime

def date_sort(filename):
    abc, hms, ymd = filename.split('_')
    return datetime.strptime(hms + ymd, ''%H%M%S%y%m%d')
```

Comment: Thanks, answer I went for. For anyone else who ends up on this question, this is the method I went for as I'd already started trying something like this. I think sorting to a datetime object may be the more "obvious" way to do it but this definitely works.

Comment: `sort` is `O(n log n)`. You are better off with `heapq`.

Comment: @PierreD Indeed! I still think it's useful to explain sorting first, as it's more intuitive. I don't think you saw my most recent edit, though.

Answer (score 3):

First, parse the filenames as datetimes, then take the top k of those (could sort but it's faster to use `heapq`):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import heapq

files = ...  # e.g.: use glob, listdir, whatever
last2 = heapq.nlargest(2, [
    (f, datetime.strptime('_'.join(f.split('_')[-2:]), '%H%M%S_%Y%m%d'))
    for f in files
], key=lambda ft: ft[1])
```

`last2` contains tuples `(filename, datetime)`. To get just the filenames (here on some synthetic list of filenames):

```
>>> [f for f, t in last2]
['abc_091500_20210124', 'abc_090000_20210124']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `datetime` module to convert the date from strings to datetime object and sort on it

```
import datetime as DT

directory = os.listdir("logs")

sorted_log = sorted(directory, key=lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, "abc_%H%M%S_%Y%m%d"))
```

`sorted_log` is a list of your filenames sorted according to date and time. The last two are the two most recent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
import os

a, b = sorted(os.listdir("logs"), key=lambda x: int(''.join(x.split('_')[1:])))[:-2]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Explanation:

1. `sorted(os.listdir("logs")` returns the list of files in the `logs` folder sorted alphabetically. That is not what we want.
2. Insert a custom key, using the keyword argument, `key`. Instead of defining a whole other function, you can use the `lambda` method:

```
sorted(os.listdir("logs"), key=lambda x: x)
```

3. Use `x.split('_')` in the lambda function to get a list of all the strings separated by a `'_'`, and the slice `[1:]` to omit the base:

```
sorted(os.listdir("logs"), key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1:])
```

4. Use the `list.join()` method to merge the two string in `x.split('_')[1:]` into a single string, and use `int()` to convert the resulting string into an integer:

```
sorted(os.listdir("logs"), key=lambda x: int(''.join(x.split('_')[1:])))
```

5. Finally, use the slice `[:-2]` to get the two most recent files, and unpack the array returned by the slice into the two variables `a` and `b`:

```
a, b = sorted(os.listdir("logs"), key=lambda x: int(''.join(x.split('_')[1:])))[:-2]
```

---

Another way is to use the [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strptime) and [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) methods:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

base = "abc"
a, b = sorted(datetime.strptime(file, f"{base}_%H%M%S_%Y%m%d") for file in os.listdir("logs"))[:-2]

print(a.strftime(f"{base}_%H%M%S_%Y%m%d"))
print(b.strftime(f"{base}_%H%M%S_%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: it works in this particular case, but the generic answer is to parse the datetime. I have seen people use really crazy date formatting, e.g. `'%b-%d-%y'`; sigh.