# Group data by a given Range

Tags: python, algorithm

im looking for an algorithm to get different means for different values.
Example:
I have the values 1.6, 1.7, 5.6, 5.7, 5,5
So the Output should be 1.65 and 5.7

Comment: What's the rule you use to decide which values belong to which? The answer to that is important in figuring out what algorithm to use. Could be a very simple grouping problem or a very complex clustering problem.

Comment: Are you allowed to use built in functions like a reduce or group call?

Comment: I suggest reading a bit about different clustering algorithms, and you can play around with their [implementation in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: I give a range of 0.4 so the values have to be in the range [1.6;2] in the example

Comment: maybe it could be useful if you know my project: i have a gauge reader where i have to read to 2 different pointers out. So i used houghlines to detects those lines and now i want to read out every line and get the mean of it.

Comment: Some information is still missing. For example, if you get `{1.0 1.3 1.6}`, how will you perform the grouping?

Comment: Wait, so, you already know that there will be exactly two groups??

Comment: Then it should be the interval [0.9;1.7] by a given range of 0.4

Comment: yes there will be 1-2 group(s) it depends how close those pointers are

Comment: Well, just sort the list of values, look for the greatest gap, and split the list at the greatest gap??  `[1.6, 1.7, 5.6, 5.7, 5.5]` -> sort -> `[1.6, 1.7, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7]` -> measure the gaps -> `[0.1, 3.8, 0.1, 0.1]` -> the greatest gap is the second gap (3.8) -> `[1.6, 1.7]` "split here" `[5.5, 5.6, 5.7]`

Comment: I feel like @Stef has all the comments in the thread that are necessary and essential to solve the problem. Way to go!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you know the "range" around each cluster mean

A possible simple solution: round every value to a multiple of your "range" parameter; group values that are rounded to the same multiple.

To group, you can use a combination of `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`, or more simply, you can use a `dict` of `lists`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def clusters(data, r):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for x in data:
        groups[x // r].append(x)
    return groups

def means_of_clusters(data, r):
    return [sum(g) / len(g) for g in clusters(data, r).values()]

print( means_of_clusters([1.6, 1.7, 5.6, 5.7, 5.5], 0.4) )
# [1.65, 5.55, 5.7]
```

Note how 5.7 was separated from 5.5 and 5.6, because 5.5 and 5.6 were rounded to `13*0.4`, whereas 5.7 was rounded to `14*0.4`.

### If you know the number of clusters

You mentioned in the comments that there will always be 2 clusters. I suggest just looking for the greatest gap between two consecutive numbers in the sorted list, and splitting on that gap:

```py
def split_in_2_clusters(data):
    seq = sorted(data)
    split_index = max(range(1, len(seq)), key=lambda i: seq[i] - seq[i-1])
    return seq[:split_index], seq[split_index:]

def means_of_2_clusters(data):
    return tuple(sum(g) / len(g) for g in split_in_2_clusters(data))

print( means_of_2_clusters([1.6, 1.7, 5.6, 5.7, 5.5]) )
# (1.65, 5.6000000000000005)
```

### For more complex clustering problems

I strongly suggest taking a look at all the clustering algorithms implemented in library **scikit-learn**. The documentation page lists the algorithms in a nice table that explains which parameters are expected by which algorithm; so you can easily choose the algorithm best-suited to your situation.

- [scikit-learn: Clustering algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: i tried your code but there is a little problem. I have a gauge reader which is always rotating so the lines could be near to 0 and 9 so  if the pointer is nearby 0.1 there are nearby pointers on 9.9 so it takes the 9.9 as the greatest value.

Comment: @GetBoosted so you are saying that the values should be handled as if they were on a circle rather than on a line?

Comment: imagine you have a pointer pointing to 0.1. This pointer is about 0.3 wide on the scale. The lines that my hoghlines recognizes then also go to the 9.9 and then the largest distance is from e.g. 5 to 9.9.

Comment: yes its a gauge reader, the values are on a circle

Comment: @GetBoosted If the values are around a circle, then you need to find two split points rather than just one; and since 10 and 0 are equivalent, instead of `seq[i] - seq[i-1]` in the `split_in_two_clusters` function, you should use the distance `min(abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1]), 10 - abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1]))`

Comment: Or if you're lazy and don't care about heavier-than-needed calculations, use the geometric angle that you've measured, take the sin and cos of that angle to get a point in the plane, and use scikit-learn's k-means clustering or another of scikit-learn's clustering algorithms to get two clusters of these points in the plane.

Comment: Your first suggestion did not work, I still get the same result.

Comment: @GetBoosted I am not in your head. What is "my first suggestion"? [What does "did not work" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work) What is "the same result"?

Comment: Your suggestion with the min(abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1]), 10 - abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1])). It produces the same result as before the change

Comment: @GetBoosted Did you really implement it correctly? In particular, did you take the first half of the sentence into account? Let me repeat myself: *"If the values are around a circle, then you need to find two split points rather than just one"*. Do you agree that in order to cut a line in two halves, only one scissorcut is needed; but in order to cut a circle in two halves, you need two scissor cuts?

Comment: Oh I must have missed that, sorry. Can you maybe explain to me what you mean by that?

Comment: Ah yeah thats true. But i have no idea how i can afford this.

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can adjust your code to cut it into 2 splitpoints? Im a beginner in Python.

Comment: @GetBoosted First thing to do, instead of getting the one index of the largest gap, you should find the two indices of the two largest gaps. Now, if you type in "maximum two elements python" in your favourite search engines, the very first result will probably be that page: [Retrieve the two highest items from a list containing 100000 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-two-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers).

Comment: So you can start by adding `from heapq import nlargest` at the top of your code, and replacing `split_index = max(range(1, len(seq)), key=lambda i: seq[i] - seq[i-1])` with `i, j = nlargest(2, range(1, len(seq)), key=lambda i: min(abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1]), 10 - abs(seq[i] - seq[i-1])))`

Comment: Now to simplify things, make sure they are correctly ordered: `i, j = min(i, j), max(i, j)`

Comment: Now your list is split into three parts: `seq[:i], seq[i:j], seq[j:]`

Comment: But the first part and the last part go together, as the list represents a circle; so you can write `return seq[j:] + seq[:i], seq[i:j]`