# Find the largest and second largest integer in a vector of integers in 1.5n comparisons

Tags: algorithm, rust

I am trying to determine the largest and second-largest elements in a vector of integers in Rust in approximately 1.5n operations. (This is an exercise from a book I am reading).

My approach is to iterate into the array up till **n/2** to select a pair of integers, and then compare the integers to determine which is larger. The larger number is placed in a new array **L**, while the smaller number is added to another array **S**.

The logic is that the largest number should be in the array **L**, while the second largest number should be either in the array **L** or the array **S**. A different comparison will be used for this.

The first step should take n/2 operations while the others ideally should take less than n operations which will be approximately 1.5n operations.

I have written a program for this using Rust, the program outputs the correct answer sometimes but most of the time, it outputs the wrong answer.

I have tried debugging it and issues I have found:

- when iterating up to ***n/2***, the program is unable to access the last element in the vector when the size of the vector is odd. If it iterated up to ***(n + 1)/2*** I get an out-of-bounds error.
- the code cannot determine if the largest and second largest numbers are of the same index. (They should not be of the same index, this is more of me lacking an idea of how to implement this).

Here is the program I have developed:

```
pub fn max_pairwise_product_faster(a: &Vec<i64>) -> i64 {

    let n = (a.len()) / 2;
    let mut larger_numbers: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();
    let mut smaller_numbers: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();
    println!("n: {}", n);

    for i in 0..n {
        if a[2 * i] > a[2 * i + 1] {
            larger_numbers.push(a[2 * i]);
            smaller_numbers.push(a[2 * i + 1]);
        } else {
            larger_numbers.push(a[2 * i * 1]);
            smaller_numbers.push(a[2 * i]);
        }
    }

    println!(
        "larger_numbers: {:?}, smaller_numbers: {:?}",
        larger_numbers, smaller_numbers
    );

    let largest = larger_numbers.iter().max().unwrap();

    // Determine the second-largest number
    let mut second_largest = smaller_numbers.iter().max().unwrap();
    //Check if there is any number higher than this in the larger_number vector
    for number in &larger_numbers {
        if number != largest && number > second_largest {
            second_largest = number;
        }
    }

    println!(
        "largest_number: {}, second_largest_number: {}",
        largest, second_largest
    );

    largest * second_largest
}
```

Here is a sample input and the output for the current implementation:

```
input array: [3, 5, 8, 20, 8, 7, 11, 20, 5, 16]
n: 5
larger_numbers: [3, 8, 8, 11, 5], smaller_numbers: [3, 8, 7, 11, 5]
largest_number: 11, second_largest_number: 11
Wrong answer -> naive: 400, fast: 121
```

In this instance, the correct answer should be 400 but the code doesn't even get the largest number correctly.

I do not want the exact code for this but a walk-through on how I can implement this.

Comment: Are you asking for how to fix your specific implementation or any solution to the problem?

Comment: You can sort array in descending order and pick first and second elements.

Comment: @code I want to fix my specific implementation or a solution that takes about 1.5n comparison to get the result.

Comment: @KhaledAlam That could work, but as I do not know the implementation under the hood for the sort function I am not sure it will be 1.5n operations.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739051/retrieve-the-two-highest-item-from-a-list-containing-100-000-integers

Comment: I know how to achieve this with 1.5n operations.  But doing so is MUCH slower than 2 linear scans.

Comment: @btilly please could you work me through the 1.5n operations? I know it is not the best solution but I would like to see it.

Comment: Note that the largest product can result from the two *smallest* factors. Which is why *min&max* creeps up in comments&answers.

Comment: There's a bug in your index selection in the first loop: `a[2 * i * 1]`, you want `+ 1`, not `* 1`. That is the heart of your issue here, leading to skip some of the odd indices, and as it turns out the `20` are both at odd indices.

Comment: Thank you @MatthieuM.I didn't catch that. I will try it out now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Algorithm

I expect that @greybeard made the key observation [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499021):

> Anyway, if you compare each element to the current second-largest, I expect comparisons to the largest value to become increasingly unlikely.

The reason is that should the input be random, then:

- The largest value of the first half, is likely amongst the largest of the second half.
- Ditto for the second largest value of the first half.

At the extreme, let's say the two largest values are the first two values you start with:

- Comparing to the largest first, and the second largest second if the value is lower than the first will *always* lead to 2 comparisons.
- Comparing to the second largest first, and the largest second if the value is greater than the second will *always* lead to a single comparison.

Of course, you won't know the largest or second largest immediately. In average, you'll know them after looking at 50% of the elements, and thus you'll do 2 comparisons for each element in the first half, and 1 comparison for each element in the second half, for a total of 1.5N comparisons.

##### Rusting it up

We should have a signature of the form:

```rust
fn max_pairwise_product(values: &[i64]) -> Option<i64>;
```

Firstly, if `values` is empty, there'll be no product of any sort.

Secondly, note the use of `&[i64]` as argument, rather than `&Vec<i64>`: it's more generic. You can get a `&[T]` from a `Vec<T>`, a `VecDeque<T>`, a `[T; N]`, ...

##### Imperative

Let's code imperatively first ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4eff6ef616d34d44fee888bddb0e2507)):

```rust
fn max_pairwise_product(values: &[i64]) -> Option<i64> {
    //  `[T]::get` returns an `Option<&T>`.
    //  `Option<&T>::copied` returns an `Option<T>`, if `T` is `Copy.
    //  `?` short-circuits the operation when things don't work out.
    let first = values.get(0).copied()?;
    let second = values.get(1).copied()?;

    //  Can be expressed as `(first.max(second), first.min(second))` too.
    let (mut first, mut second) = if first > second {
        (first, second)
    } else {
        (second, first)
    };

    //  And from then, we scan the rest of the values using sub-slicing to
    //  express that we want to skip the first 2 values.
    //  The `&` in front of `v` is pattern-matching to make `v` a value,
    //  instead of a reference.
    for &v in &values[2..] {
        if v <= second {
            continue;
        }

        if v <= first {
            second = v;
            continue;
        }

        second = first;
        first = v;
    }

    Some(first * second)
}
```

##### Functional

Rust does have more tricks upon its sleeve, though, and in particular pattern-matching (more) and replacing loops with `Iterator` methods can yield pretty sweet code.

The same algorithm can in fact be expressed as ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61ce184919c095e7d58f398928d7e89b)):

```rust
fn max_pairwise_product(values: &[i64]) -> Option<i64> {
    //  The all-powerful `let .. else` form of pattern-matching, the "my way
    //  or the highway" style of matching for quickly getting out of here.
    let [first, second, tail @ ..] = values else { return None };

    let (first, second) = (first.max(second), first.min(second));

    let (first, second) = tail
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .fold((*first, *second), |(first, second), v| {
            if v <= second {
                (first, second)
            } else if v <= first {
                (first, v)
            } else {
                (v, first)
            }
        });

    Some(first * second)
}
```

This is using pattern-matching on slice to extract the elements in a visual manner (_though the `tail @ ..` part is nightly only at the moment), and the mighty `fold` algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Matthieu, It works well in my code. Thank you for also pointing out the Rust way!

Comment: I chose the style I did because I was running a stress test script on it with other implementations.

Comment: @Orukele: You don't have to defend your choices :) We obviously only have limited information about the context in which you're using the code. I am just pointing that _in isolation_ the signature I proposed is probably best, and leaving you free to decide whether in the context of your work it's actually better or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what all the fanciness in your algorithm yields. It seems a lot more productive to just use two variables and only iterate once.

```rust
fn max_pairwise_product(a: &Vec<i64>) -> i64 {
    // assign to first values
    let (mut largest, mut second_largest) = (i64::MIN, i64::MIN);

    // only one iteration
    for &i in a.iter() {
        if i > largest {
            // i is larger than both, so shift the positions
            (largest, second_largest) = (i, largest);
        } else if i > second_largest {
            // i is only larger than the second largest, so change that
            second_largest = i;
        }
    }
    largest * second_largest
}
```

Comment: If the list was `[10, 2]`, this would print `100`, right? I don't think that's the intended behavior.

Comment: @isaactfa you're absolutely right, I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but it does not pass the case where there are two elements in the array and the first one is larger than the second one. E.g.` [20, 11]`. 

It has to do with the initialisation of `largest` and `second_largest`. Setting the to zero works fine

Comment: @isaactfa actually I'm not exactly sure how those edge cases _should_ be handled... the OP didn't specify. What if the two inputs are same? I could go the `i64::MIN` route but that might yield strange results in other cases.

Comment: @Stargateur the function signature _is_ just a copy of the OP's...

Comment: @code apologies if it wasn't clear but in my initial question I mentioned that the largest and second largest_number should not be in the same index.

Comment: I think the only edge cases are singleton and empty lists. The code is still wrong, I think. `[10, 2, 1]` will still print `100`. You should set `largest` to `max(a[0], a[1])` and `second_largest` to `min(a[0], a[1])`

Comment: @isaactfa that's fair, but given the OP's clarification just setting both values to the minimum i64 value should do the trick.

Comment: Sure. Although now empty and singleton lists will overflow because you're returning `i64::MIN ^ 2`.

Comment: @isaactfa ;) right, just add a case to see if the length < 2, but the OP didn't define what behavior should arise should that happen, so I assume it won't.

Comment: I think I would code it like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c8d65ef5cd45a9e996246c97de2e73ab

Comment: @Stargateur you should add it as an answer. Not too familiar with Rust and couldn't come up with that myself, although the current solution seems straightforward.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, it has really been helpful!

Comment: use dummy value like `i64::MIN` is very not the way to have robust code, I would not recommend it specially in Rust.

Comment: @Stargateur sure, never learned Rust in university, but that's what they taught for C++...

Comment: C++ added https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional for a reason.

Comment: @Stargateur too bad I had to deal with C++11 back then.

Comment: I don't see how that change in anyway what I'm saying, are you just closed to better code practice ? we are in 2023 and make big process since C++11.

Comment: @Stargateur don't mean to start an argument, just want to mention that I'm currently not following the trends of C++ (nor Rust) and thus am not up to date with "best practices".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do *get second-largest* (or *two largest*) with an *expected* number of comparisons of 1.5*n*, or better than 2*n worst case*.

There are two interpretations of *second-largest*:
in `0, 1, 2, 2` the *two largest* are `2, 2`, but I'd call `1` *second-largest* here.

Anyway, if you compare each element to the current *second-largest*, I expect comparisons to the largest value to become increasingly unlikely.
With "uniformly random input", I'd expect n+nᵏ comparisons, with k not even ½.

There have been many questions about finding the largest product with few comparisons as well as answers.

Comment: _"Anyway, if you compare each element to the current second-largest, I expect comparisons to the largest value to become increasingly unlikely."_ => This is the key observation I was disappointed not to see in other answers. For a random input, comparing the largest first will likely be false forcing a comparison with the second largest every time... leading to 2N comparisons. And for best effect, a median-of-median selection at the beginning probably helps against somewhat adversarial inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it, and your concerns are correct. They can be eliminated logically.

First, you can simply check the last element if the length is odd. This is two comparisons in the worst case.

Second, you can keep track of the index of the max element.

I've swapped your algorithm around a little to make this easier. I'm using the original slice for storage, making the first half the larger numbers and the second half smaller numbers. Then, I'm running the naive algorithm on the first half. This gives me two numbers and indices. I then check the smaller half at the index corresponding to max's index, since that is the only number in the smaller half that could be greater than the second-max.

And finally, I check the last element if the length was odd.

This algorithm does N/2 comparisons on the first phase, just like yours. The second phase uses a 2N algorithm on half the list. Then there are 3 extra comparisons. In total, this is N/2 + 2N/2 + 3 or O(1.5N).

```rs
fn reordering_(a: &mut [i64]) -> i64 {
    let mid = a.len() / 2;
    let (half1, half2) = a.split_at_mut(mid);

    // Put max items in the first half
    for (x, y) in half1.iter_mut().zip(half2) {
        if y > x {
            std::mem::swap(x, y);
        }
    }

    // Find two largest in first half
    let mut largest = [(i64::MIN, 0), (i64::MIN, 0)];
    for (index, &i) in a[..mid].iter().enumerate() {
        if i > largest[1].0 {
            if i > largest[0].0 {
                largest = [(i, index), largest[0]]
            } else {
                largest[1] = (i, index);
            }
        }
    }

    let matching = largest[0].1 + mid;
    let mut largest = largest.map(|(n, _)| n);

    if a[matching] > largest[1] {
        largest[1] = a[matching];
    }

    if a.len() % 2 == 1 {
        let &last = a.last().unwrap();
        if last > largest[1] {
            if last > largest[0] {
                largest.reverse();
                largest[0] = last;
            } else {
                largest[1] = last;
            }
        }
    }

    largest[0] * largest[1]
}
```

Comment: I don't see `half2` put to good use.

Comment: @drewtato thank you for your solution. I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Orukele BTW all the other answers are 2N algorithms. You can test them with ascending and descending sequences to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot better than 1.5n comparisons.

The key point to understand is this:  **In order to determine the largest element, you must, at some point, compare it to the second-largest element**.

You can use this to get the largest and second-largest in only n + ceil(log<sub>2</sub> n) - 2 comparisons.

First, in order to find the largest element divide the elements into pairs, compare the elements in each pair, and select all the ceil(n/2) winners.  Repeat this process on the winners until only the largest element remains.  This is like an elimination tournament.

This process of finding the largest element takes ceil(log<sub>2</sub> n) rounds, and does n-1 comparisons all together.  In each round, the largest element is compared at most once, against the element it was paired with.  Gather these pair-mates and use ceil(log<sub>2</sub> n)-1 comparisons to find the largest of those.  That will be the second-largest element.

Comment: (Knuth 5.3.3 Theorem S. (Proposed by J. Schreier, first known non-refuted proof credited to S.S. Kislitsyn - 32 years later))